# How do i design a schema with proper DB engine to accumulate data depending on this need on clickhouse or in any other database?

Tags: sql, database-design, clickhouse, database-engine

We're a new Adtech company and I was planning to design a database where I'll pull all the data to a single table and then make new tables with a materialized views for others to generate multiple reports.

Say we have Inventory, impression, views for multiple reasons.

[image]

Our main table looks like this, to recreate this

```
CREATE TABLE report.empty_summing (times DateTime64,inventory_id String,city Nullable(String), country Nullable(String),inventory Int32 default 0, impression Int32 default 0, views Int32 default 0) ENGINE=SummingMergeTree() primary key inventory_id;
```

When a request comes from google ADX to our Adengine , it has a unique id which is "inventory_id" and other parameters like country, city..... other string type parameters are inserted.

When 3 types of data are inserted it looks like this.

[image]

You can see that Every row have their values inserted but I want to

Our inventory request insert looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO report.empty_summing (times,inventory_id,country,city,inventory,impression,views) VALUES (now(),'7120426e6abd0b04ec8c777460a78bdf4b9de0','Bangladesh','Dhaka',1,0,0);
```

Our impression insert looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO report.empty_summing (times,inventory_id,impression) VALUES (now(),'7120426e6abd0b04ec8c777460a78bdf4b9de0',1);
```

Our view insert looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO report.empty_summing (times,inventory_id,views) VALUES (now(),'7120426e6abd0b04ec8c777460a78bdf4b9de0',1);
```

You can see that "inventory_id" is the same for all these rows. is there any DB engine or any technique I can use where data will be merged and look like this?

[image]

Help is much appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: That's an aggregation query, supported by every database I've ever come across.

Comment: okay but using group by query, the results are not what i expected @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and explain further, including the query you used. Also please use text rather than pictures

Comment: It's worth thinking about data size - if you're an adtech company, presumably you're handling millions of requests / day, so this table could very easily grow to billions or trillions of records.
While I agree with @Nick.McDermaid that this looks like a trivial query on every RDBMS, "trillions of records" may present a problem. I recommend Kleppmann's book for perspective on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleAggregateFunction(any, Nullable(String))

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/28073#issuecomment-905151779

https://gist.github.com/den-crane/d03524eadbbce0bafa528101afa8f794